# Rol of java api classes within JRE

Tags: java

I am beginner with java.

I've following question.

1. Does JRE automatically comes with JDK installation?or, do we need to install JDK and JRE separately?
2. JRE has two components - i. Java API classes and ii.JVM

I know how JVM works but I want to know what's the role of Java API classes within JRE?What works it does?

3.What's the relation between JRE and JVM?How JRE helps in execution of JVM?

4. How JRE interacts with OS?
5. How JRE interacts with hardware?

Comment: JDK contains everything you need

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Does JRE automatically comes with JDK installation?or, do we need to install JDK and JRE separately?

If you just install the JRE, that's all you get. If you install the JDK, it installs both the JDK and a JRE (by default, the JRE is installed to a `jre` subdirectory of where you install the JDK).

> 2. JRE has two components - i. Java API classes and ii.JVM
>
> I know how JVM works but I want to know what's the role of Java API classes within JRE?What works it does?

The API classes are available to be used in Java programs. So if you write a Java program, you know that you'll have a large set of pre-built classes you can use for things. For instance, you know that there will be a `Map` interface and an implementation of it called `HashMap`, so if you need a hash map in your application code, there's one ready and waiting for you.

> 3.What's the relation between JRE and JVM?How JRE helps in execution of JVM?

As you said above, the JVM is *part of* the JRE.

> 4. How JRE interacts with OS?

I don't understand this question. The JRE, per se, doesn't really; the JVM does. The JVM is specific to the OS (there's a different JVM for Windows than *nix, for instance, although of course as much of the code is common to both as possible).

> 5. How JRE interacts with hardware?

The same way any other program written for an operating system does: Through the operating system's API, if possible, or direct to the machine's hardware if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the jdk,both jdk and jre are installed,so there is no need of installing each separately.As for the API classes,they are to be used in your program.You can use an API using the import statement(java.lang does not require it) at the beginning of your program.
The JVM is the java interpreter.You probably know that java programs are both compiled and interpreted.After compilation,the compiler converts the source code into a machine independent intermediate form called byte code.It is this byte code which makes java platform independent.The JVM,during execution,translates the byte code to machine code.This is how execution of a java program occurs.So,it is this JVM which is OS specific.